# Fonts Look Fuzzy on Windows 7 - Possibly Just Google Fonts?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, google-font-api

On web pages that seem to use the Google fonts, well, basically the font is all fuzzy. I've checked across Chrome/Firefox/IE and it's the same thing and it's slowly driving me mad. As a web developer - it's proving to be more of a migraine than a headache

**[EDIT]**

I added `127.0.0.1` fonts.googleapis.com to my hosts file and whilst some sites render the default Arial, FB and SO still show the blurry font

Below are examples of what I mean

[image: Stackoverflow]

[image: Facebook]

Comment: No ClearType.  This belongs at superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

I had the Helvetica Neue font installed on my machine. Removed it and it worked fine.